# Node.js set attribute checked of select in web page

Tags: html, node.js, wab

I'm learning node.js now. I face a problem that, I get data from index.html page , I want to sent several value on the second page, for example ,  ....  one option has been selected. 
how can I do this, in the situation: don't change anything on second page.

Thank you

Comment: Please edit your question and paste the code you're using for doing this.

Comment: send value as a json